# Copy selected cells from one workbook and copy to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a database which will copy a selected range of data from a main workbook and copy into a separate workbook.

The code causing the issue is below. The 2nd workbook opens based on the value of "W2". A new row should be inserted to the new Wb and formatted then the value of the selected cells pasted.

```
'Select data to be copied
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 4).Copy

'Open Lessons Learned Db
Location = Range("W2").Value
Set Lessons = Workbooks.Open(Location)
Set LL = Sheets("Lessons Learned")
Windows("Lessons Learned Database.XLSM").Activate
Sheets("Lessons Learned").Activate

'Insert New Row
Range("5:5").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
'Enter Odd Or Even VALUE
    Range("A7").Select
    OE = ActiveCell.Value
    If OE = 1 Then
        Range("A6").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 0
    Else
        Range("A6").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 1
    End If

'Hide Permanently Hidden Rows -LINE BELOW GIVES ERROR 1004
    Rows("5:5").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Columns("A").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
'FORMAT ROW
    Range("A6").Select
    SC = ActiveCell.Value
        If SC = 1 Then
    Range("B6:N6").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .ColorIndex = 15
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

End If
Range("B5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Any pointer on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its advised not to use `.Select` or `.Activate` as there are other ways to accomplish this.
Because you were selecting and activating this could have caused the `ERROR 1004`.

Below i have "cleaned up" your code defining `Lessons`, `LL` and `Location` and included `MainWB` and defined your ranges.

By defining your `Range` Excel will always get the `.Value` from that `Range` there is then no need to use `.Select` or `.Activate`.

As far as tested the below code works:

```
Sub CopyMainWBtoNewWB()

Dim Lessons As Workbook
Dim LL As Worksheet
Dim MainWB As Workbook
Dim Location As String

Set MainWB = Workbooks("Name Here")

'Open Lessons Learned Db
Location = MainWB.Sheets("Sheet Name").Range("W2").Value
Set Lessons = Workbooks.Open(Location)
Set LL = Lessons.Sheets("Lessons Learned")

'Insert New Row
LL.Rows(5).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

'Enter Odd Or Even VALUE
If LL.Range("A7").Value = 1 Then
    LL.Range("A6").Value = 0
Else
    LL.Range("A6").Value = 1
End If

'Hide Permanently Hidden Rows -LINE BELOW GIVES ERROR 1004
LL.Rows(5).Hidden = True
LL.Columns(1).Hidden = True

'FORMAT ROW

If LL.Range("A6").Value = 1 Then
    With LL.Range("B6:N6").Interior
        .ColorIndex = 15
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
End If
MainWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Copy
LL.Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

All you need to do is change the `Workbook` name of `MainWB` and the `Sheet` name its collecting the `Value`for `Location`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your code has some other issues that Code Review may be able to help with but to answer your question:

The `Rows("5:5").Select` is being passed the wrong argument data type.

`Worksheet.Rows()` is expecting a number, either Integer or Long data type but you are giving it a string.

Change it to `Rows(5)` and it should work.

Comment: This is a good example of the 'loose typing' aspect of VBA. That code line will work. `?rows("5:5").address` in the VBE's Immediate window returns `$5:$5` as it should.

Comment: @Jeeped, you are correct on both counts. I should have tested instead of jumping in. So I can't produce the `1004 Application-defined or object-defined error` condition.  What am I missing?

Comment: I tried to make sense of the code but I really only think in non-Select/Activate terms so I would have to rewrite it. Since there is no indication of what the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) is at the beginning of the code, anything I tried would be a shot in the dark so I am bowing out.

Answer (score 1):

That can all be consolidated to:

```
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 4).Copy '// not sure what this is for

Set Lessons = Workbooks.Open([w2])
Set LL = Lessons.Sheets("Lessons Learned")

With LL
    .Rows(6).EntireRow.Insert
    .Range("A6").value = IIf(.Range("A7").value = 1, 0, 1)
    .Rows(5).Hidden = True
    .Columns("A").Hidden = True
        If .Range("A6").value = 1 Then
            With .Range("B6:N6").Interior
                .ColorIndex = 15
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        End If
    .Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```

You will notice that this code refers directly to each object without activating or selecting it. Coding in this way means that every object is fully qualified and you know exactly which instance you are working with.

This should ensure that the row is correctly hidden without error because you are referring to the `Rows` collection which is a collection of `Ranges` with defined properties and methods. `Selection` can be a sheet, workbook, chart, range or pretty much anything else you can point and click at - so this can cause problems when trying to access properties or methods that belong to a particular object or class.